How to create "attributes" field in on chain metadata for TON NFT item
I'm currently working on an NFT collection on the TON network. I want all metadata to be placed "on chain" and created inside the contract since there will be a public mint option. I managed to place all of them except the "attributes" parameter. Could someone provide an example of how to do this inside the contract?
Here is example of what I have now.
cell attributes = begin_cell().store_int(0,8).store_slice("{'trait_type':'trait_name','value':'trait_value'}").end_cell();

metadata_dict~udict_set_ref(256, "attributes"H, attributes);

